# Spider Chart in Victory Native

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm trying to create a spider chart in Victory Native but I need the edges of the radar axis(VictoryPolarAxis) to be straight like this

The chart I expect looks like this:

[spider chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkSp1.png)

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to draw a line chart in polar coordinates and then use Victory's customization api to draw the straight lines you need.

[Output of Polar Chart Image for below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJfmZ.png)

Refer to the following code

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  VictoryChart,
  VictoryLine,
  VictoryPolarAxis,
  VictoryTheme
} from "victory";
import React from "react";

const sampleDataPolar = [
  { x: "E", y: 1 },
  { x: "NE", y: 1.9 },
  { x: "N", y: 1.5 },
  { x: "NW", y: 2 },
  { x: "W", y: 2.1 },
  { x: "SW", y: 1.8 },
  { x: "S", y: 1.9 },
  { x: "SE", y: 0.7 },
  { x: "E", y: 1 }
];

function CircularAxisComponent(props) {
  const centerX = props.cx;
  const centerY = props.cy;
  const radius = props.r;
  const angularGap = 360 / (sampleDataPolar.length - 1);
  const pts = Array(sampleDataPolar.length)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, idx) => {
      const angle_deg = angularGap * idx;
      const angle_rad = (Math.PI / 180) * angle_deg;

      const pointX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle_rad);
      const pointY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle_rad);
      return `${pointX},${pointY}`;
    })
    .join(",");
  return <polygon points={pts} fill="none" stroke="lightgrey" />;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <VictoryChart
        polar
        theme={VictoryTheme.material}
        domainPadding={{ y: 40 }}
      >
        <VictoryPolarAxis
          tickCount={8}
          circularAxisComponent={<CircularAxisComponent />}
        />

        <VictoryLine
          data={sampleDataPolar}
          style={{ data: { fill: "transparent", strokeWidth: 2 } }}
          polar
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let's dive in.

Creating a line chart in polar form is fairly easy. Just pass your data to the **VictoryLine** component and set the **polar** property to true.

For replacing the circular arc of the axis with straight lines, use the **VictoryPolarAxis**.
In the example above, this component takes a prop called `circularAxisComponent` that allows us to customize how the axis is rendered.

I created a functional component called **CircularAxisComponent** that draws this axis.

All this component does is render a SVG polygon. Getting the coordinates of the point requires a bit of maths and trigonometry.

```js
const pointX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle_rad);
const pointY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle_rad);
```

In the calculation for **pointX**, `radius * cos(t)` gives the X coordinate and adding **centerX** will translate this point so that the resulting polygon appears at the correct position. Same for y coordinate.

To checkout other ways you can customize the Polar Axis component, refer to the docs - [Victory Docs - VictoryPolarAxis](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-polar-axis)